# Telerik Report not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, report

I'm trying to use Telerik Q3 Reporting

When I'm changing anything in the report like a textbox's text it didn't reflect at runtime or preview, I make the report viewer `EnableViewState=False` but no reflection

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="NoranReporting._Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=7.2.13.1016, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be"
    Namespace="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<telerik:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ZoomMode="FullPage" 
        EnableViewState="False" Height="100%" ProgressText="يتم تجهيز التقرير..." 
        Width="100%" ></telerik:ReportViewer>   
</asp:Content>
```

This is picture from design

http://postimg.org/image/41b4o3yu5/

and this is picture from runtime

http://postimg.org/image/htpjjqplp/

And why the report height is to small like this?

I tried

```
ZoomMode="FullPage" Height="100%"
```

but as you can see in the picture, it didn't work

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="NoranReporting.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    My ASP.NET Application
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Css File:

```
/* DEFAULTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

  html#html, body#body, form#form1, div#content, center#center
  { 
   border: 0px solid black;

   float:right;
   height: 100%;
  }

body   
{
    background: #b6b7bc;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #034af3;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
    color: #034af3;
}

p
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #666666;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* this rule styles <h1> and <h2> tags that are the 
first child of the left and right table columns */
.rightColumn > h1, .rightColumn > h2, .leftColumn > h1, .leftColumn > h2
{
    margin-top: 0px;
}


/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.page
{
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;
}

.header
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #4b6c9e;
    width: 100%;
}

.header h1
{
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 420px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    direction:rtl;
}

.leftCol
{
    padding: 6px 0px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
{
    color: #4e5766;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
}


/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#3a4f63;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* FORM ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset
{
    margin: 1em 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset p 
{
    margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
}

fieldset.login label, fieldset.register label, fieldset.changePassword label
{
    display: block;
}

fieldset label.inline 
{
    display: inline;
}

legend 
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input.textEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.passwordEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.accountInfo
{
    width: 42%;
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.title
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}

.loginDisplay
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    color: White;
}

.loginDisplay a:link
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:visited
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:hover
{
    color: white;
}

.failureNotification
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: Red;
}

.bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.submitButton
{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

i uploaded a project sample with db sample here is the link:

https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/add6db1cf706b3b044515342a0deb8ed20140521092303/3d5b86d6b747eddcc8861d858c32711d20140521092303/c08aab

Here is a sample Project with sample DB
I use VS 2013
SQL 2008
Telerik DevCraft Ultimate Q3 2013

1-The Main problem that the text box's text not updated even at preview tab of report 
at the design mode text box's value is "تقرير تفصيلى " 
but at run time or preview it viewed the text box's text "Report1"

2-the viewer is not 100% height of page

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code for the Master page it looks to me like the BodyContent is too small for the report viewer, you can see the scroll bar for the report on the left.

Comment: ok, cant see anything obvious in the master page that would limit the page size. As for the report not updating, what do you see on the preview tab is this what u expect?

Comment: yes preview is good at report size but it's not updating data as is said before the main problem i ask about is that i update textbox's text at the report but at run time or preview tab i didn't see any thing i changed , i try to clean the solution and make enable view state false but no update neither

Comment: I wanted to check the preview tab as it could have been an issue linking your web application to the reports dll. Ok just to check the top row is a row of textboxes on the group header and the second row is a row of textboxes on the detail group?

Comment: there are four rows at the report design
1- page header which was report1 & i made it "ادارة القوى الفنية"
2-report header which was "report1" & i made it "تقرير تفصيلى بالقوي الفنية"
3- a row of text boxes on the group header which was the column names as the binding properties refer to and i try also to change it names
4-s a row of text boxes on the detail group which is binned to data base fields and worked fine 
the first 3 rows are just text boxs that i can't update & the forth which represents data from database works fine

Comment: How do you assign the value on the textboxes that are not working? Is this in design mode in value "تقرير تفصيلى بالقوي الفنية" or is it in code?

Comment: in design mode in value "تقرير تفصيلى بالقوي الفنية" you can see the design mode pic in link at the post, 
This is picture from design
http://postimg.org/image/htpjjqplp/ ,

and this is picture from runtime
http://postimg.org/image/41b4o3yu5/